# obtener los datos de una tabla padre y los hijos de otra sin que se repita la fila del padre

Tags: php, mysql

Me gustaría obtener los datos de la tabla y los datos de los niños están en otra tabla pero no sé cómo hacer la consulta.

Lo que sé hacer es una consulta normal * forma la tabla 1, sé cómo realizar una "unión interna" pero no quiero que se repitan los datos en la tabla 1 "padre"

```
select * form padre INNER JOIN hijos on padre.pnt_id=hijos.id_pnt;
```

pero esto no me funciona para lo que necesito.

```
           padre                              hijos
+-----+----------+------+-------+   +-----+----------+-------+  
| id  |   pnt_id | info |infotwo|   | id  |   id_pnt |n_child|...  
+-----+----------+------+-------+   +-----+----------+-------+  
|    1|         7| home | big   |   |    5|         7|  joan | 
+-----+----------+------+-------+   +-----+----------+-------+  
|    2|         8| work | fat   |   |    3|         7|  luci |  
+-----+----------+------+-------+   +-----+----------+-------+  
|    3|         9| soft |  thin |   |    6|         8|  troy |  
+-----+----------+------+-------+   +-----+----------+-------+
```

me gustaria que cuando obtenga los resultados me arroje así

```
print_r($parents);

$parents = arrar (
          info -> "home",
          infotwo -> "big",
          data_child -> arrar (
                      n_child -> "joan",
                      n_child -> "luci"
                     )
)
```

Comment: obtener todos los datos solo donde info sea igual a home?

Comment: Solo quiero obtener los datos de padre y las filas de todos los hijos que tenga. si utilizo inner join no me funciona ya que me arroja doble si tiene dos hijos me da dos padres y sale duplicado el padre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo al resultado esperado, me parece que tu consulta inicia bien, pero le hace falta un condicional al final con `WHERE` para limitar los resultados de que padre quieres obtener; algo así:

Además de lo anterior, pudieras usar `GROUP_CONCAT` para concanetar en un mismo renglón todos los nombres de los hijos que le pertenecen a un padre
quedando así tu consulta.

Además de lo anterior, deberás usar al final de tu consulta `GROUP BY` con exactamente las mismas columnas de tu `SELECT` **menos** la columna que esta agrupando de forma concatenada todos los nombres de los hijos

```
SELECT padre.info,
       GROUP_CONCAT(hijos.n_child) AS Hijos
FROM padre
INNER JOIN hijos ON padre.id = hijos.id_pnt
WHERE padre.info = "home"
GROUP BY padre.info;
```

Teniendo un resultado así

Aquí te dejo un [enlace](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=56686046c62d84b1197fe01a85864077) con un ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora si quieres que todos los hijos del padre se vean pero en forma de lista es decir uno debajo de otro modifica la línea de `GROUP_CONCAT` así

```
GROUP_CONCAT(hijos.n_child SEPARATOR "\n") AS Hijos
```

Y tu resultado será así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Referencias**

- [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)